# 2001 Mercury Sable Ls

Tags: ignition, mercury, sable

I have a 2001 mercury sable that is drawing power from the battery when the vehicle is off. The amps being drawn are about .55amps. After going through the fuse panel in the passenger compartment and the engine compartment I've realized the power is being drawn by the ignition switch. When removing the fuse for the switch the amp draw returns to a normal .05amp reading. After changing the ignition switch I'm continuing to have the same issue. Also would like to note I've checked the grounds to starter and they are intact and not corroded. and starter relay seems to be working properly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the switch itself was drawing power?  Switches don't typically draw power - they allow power to be drawn by the things they "switch".

Comment: i was assuming the switch was staying open. Doing an amp test the fuse for the ignition switch was the only place i seemed to find the problem. checked grounds to everything and they all seem ok.